# VBA How To Hide Or Unhide Rows Based On Drop Down List Selection In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a Drop Down list with Multiple Options to select from source C9:C100. I would like to hide all Rows from C9 onwards except for the chosen cells corresponding row in the drop down list. I have tried the below code however it does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B4") = "True" Then
        Rows("9:100").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("9:100").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Range B4 doesn't equal "True", which is a text value literally meaning "True".  A better option would be to use a filter, it's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need an Drop Down for that, why don't you use the Autofilter?

Answer (score 0):

Test if B4 has a value, if it has find the row number with MATCH and then hide the other rows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim row As Variant
    row = Application.Match(Range("B4").Value, Range("C9:C100"), 0)
    If Not IsError(row) Then
        Rows("9:100").Hidden = True
        Rows(8 + row).Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("9:100").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```